# How to use an android module as app and library

Tags: android

I have an Android Studio project with an app module.
Currently, I am writing another module that should use the first one.
Can I have the first module (which is an app module) be used by the second one as a library?

Comment: What problem you are facing? You just need to configure that as module/ lib

Comment: How do want use it ,I mean as a module or dependency?

Comment: I have a module A which is an app. I have a module L which is a library. In L I have an Android Test which requires an Activity from A.
How do I get L to depend on A, so I can create an ActivityTestRule with Activity? (Also I need to use another Build Variant for A than for L)

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like below

In your 1st app module `gradle` you have to add your second module implementation.

```
implementation project(':your_second_module_name')
```

Also you have to update one line in your `setting.gradle`

```
include ':app', ':your_second_module_name'
```